# Putting the focus on the tray icons in Windows XP using Python

Tags: python, windows, keyboard, focus

I'm a Windows-XP-using keyboard devotee, and I want to bind <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> to put the keyboard focus on the tray icon. (Because it'll be so much nicer than <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> and then many <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd>s.)

So I'd like to make a Python program that puts the keyboard focus on the tray icons. How could I do this from Python? I know very little about controlling Windows' behavior.

If there's some ready-made program that does this, I'll be happy to hear about that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am 99% sure that there is no supported way to access the tray notification area. The actually focusable element is the overflow button, not the tray icon itself - and the Windows Shell team doesn't want to guarantee that this button will always be focusable or even that this button will exist in future Windows versions. So there is no API to access it. This is an extremely hacky way to do it, might stop working at any time - **for personal use only** (tested on Windows 7):

```
import win32gui
import win32con
taskbar = win32gui.FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd", None)
trayArea = win32gui.FindWindowEx(taskbar, None, "TrayNotifyWnd", None)
win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(taskbar)
win32gui.SendMessage(trayArea, win32con.WM_SETFOCUS, 0, 0)
```

Once again, **do not use it in an application that other people will use**. `win32gui` module is part of the [Win32 Extensions](http://starship.python.net/~skippy/win32/Downloads.html).

For the hotkey you could use [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646309%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but it should be simpler to let Explorer handle that - add a link to your script to the Start menu and define a hotkey for it.

Comment: What is the "overflow button"?

Comment: The script seems to work, but explorer (at least on XP) is unable to bind to <kbd>Start</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>. I don't use C# so RegisterHotKey doesn't help. Is there any utility to bind the shortcut key?